# Line by line profiling of a C++ program in linux, and being able to integrate in eclipse?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, profiling, callgrind

We have a project, we've being testing which involves a fair amount of math (including linear algebra, massive matrix manipulation, sparse matrices, openblas, armadillo library etc)

I asked this question because all related ones are really old. But how can I profile my project line by line so as to locate bottlenecks and find ways to ease them? Are there any new tools for that? I would also love it if the tool could integrate with Eclipse on linux.

Comment: There's gprof, it's already available in Eclipse CDT IIRC.

Comment: Can gprof do line by line profiling? Like tell me how much time each line takes?

Comment: Line by line with information how often it was executed, not sure about execution time measures. Best you check yourself:  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/

Comment: Gprof will not find your speedups, for a [*bunch of reasons*](https://archive.is/9r927). [*This will.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) [*Here's why.*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)